# Function which make uncurried curried(not using ramda library)

Tags: ocaml

I'm a beginner of Ocaml and I want to make uncurried function curried.

for example,

```
let add (x,y) = x + y
```

It is an uncurried form and I want to make a function called "curry" like

```
let inc = curry(add)(1)
let ret = inc(2)
```

If we apply my own "curry", it can be partially applied.

Since I'm the first time in Ocaml, I just thought extract entries from the tuple in the add function(quite silly...) like

```
let get_1_2 (a,_) = a
let get_2_2 (_,a) = a

let curry f tp = function
    f (get_1_2 tp) (get_2_2 tp)
```

But I know it does not make sense at all...
So How can I start?

Answer (score 0):

It is sometimes easier to try a few examples before moving to the generic case. For example, in the case of the add function, you start from

```
let add (x,y) = x + y
```

and you want to go to

```
let add2 x y = x + y
```

In this case, you can see that the right hand side of the new curried function is the same that the right hand side of the old add function. You can thus rewrite the curried function as

```
let add2 x y = add (x,y)
```

If you move to multiplication, we can do the same transformation from

```
let mult (x,y) = x * y
```

to

```
let mult2 x y = mult (x,y)
```

Now if you compare our two curried function

```
let mult2 x y = mult (x,y)
let  add2 x y  =  add (x,y)
```

The right hand side looks quite similar: they differ only by the name of the function being called on the two arguments. If we want to generalize the two function, one solution is thus to provide the function `mult` or `add` as an argument to new function. Let's call it `f` for now:

```
 let f mult_or_add x y = mult_or_add(x,y)
```

then we can rewrite `mult2` and `add2` as

```
let mult2 x y = f mult x y
let  add2 x y = f  add x y
```

The next step is to remark that `x` and `y` appears in the same position on the right hand side and left hand side of the new definition of `mult2` and `add2`, this mean that we can elide them

```
let mult2 = f mult
let  add2 = f  add
```

This means that our function `f` transforms a function taking a pair of arguments into a curried function that takes two arguments. In other words, `f` could be better called `curry2`:

```
let curry2 f x y = f (x,y)
```

A follow-up exercise might be to try writing a `curry3` or an `uncurry2` function.